# How to assign activities to users inside of teams?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

The issue I'm having in Dynamics CRM 2013 is the ability to assign activities or appointments to a team and have those cascade downward into individual users. The end goal here would be after assigning a lead or activity to a team, the users within that team would receive notifications, emails, etc. and those records would integrate with their 'my' sections of CRM.

The issue I see with this is that only 1 'Owner' can be set for a new record in all areas of CRM, and the 'my' sections are based off of the Owner. Therefore the users within the team won't be notified.

We are currently using a service to pull from an existing database and populate CRM, assigning new leads to a Team which contains multiple users.

Does anyone have a recommended method to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Either give the users a view of "Leads owned by Teams of which I am a member" or possibly use Queues, which are pretty much designed for the scenario you describe.

New items assigned to a Team will be added to the Team's Queue. Users can see all Queue Items not yet being worked on (from all Queues they have access to, including all Teams they are members of). A user can "work on" an item to show they are dealing with it so it no longer appears in this list of items to be worked on, and instead appears in their own list of items they are working on. A user can either complete the item or 'release' it back into the queue.

Queues can contain items of different types, eg Leads, Tasks, Cases etc.